# Open another BottomSheetDialogFragment from another BottomSheetDialogFragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

On clicking a view, I am opening a `BottomSheetDialogFragment`. On clicking a view inside this fragment, I need to open another `BottomSheetDialogFragment`.

MyAdapter.kt:

```kotlin
class MyAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
  ...
  var fManager: FragmentManager? = null

  inner class ViewHolder(private val binding: ViewDataBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    init {
      binding.root.setOnClickListener {
        fManager?.let { manager ->
          Dialog1().apply {
            show(manager, tag)
          }
        }
      }
    }

    ...
  }

  ...
}
```

This is my Dialog1.kt:

```kotlin
class Dialog1 : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {
  private lateinit var binding: Dialog1Binding

  override fun onCreateView(...) {...}

  override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    binding.primaryButton.setOnClickListener {
      Dialog2().apply {
        show(childFragmentManager, tag)
      }
      dismiss()
    }
  }
}
```

On the RecyclerView, Dialog1 opens as expected but when I try to open Dialog2, I get this error:

> Fragment Dialog2... has not been attached yet.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

So after a lot of trial and error, I have found out the solution is when I write the code like this:

```
binding.primaryButton.setOnClickListener {
  Dialog2().let {
    it.show(parentFragmentManager, it.tag)
  }
  dismiss()
}
```

But what was the problem with the `apply` block that I initially used?